# Number of possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the number of possible combinations of the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 such that there are only two different numbers.

My approach:

Suppose I have 5 places to fill $\text{_,_,_,_,_}$. In the first place, I can have 5 possible numbers, in the second I can have 4 possible numbers, in the third I can have 2 possible numbers (one of the two previous chosen ones), and similarly, for the 4th and 5th position, there can be 2 possible numbers. So we have the total number to be

$$5\times 4 \times 2^3 \times 5!$$

Now we need to discount all of the duplicates. We have two cases. One in which we have 4 of the same (and 1 different) and one where we have 3 of the same and 2 of another. So the total combinations must therefore be $$5\times 4 \times 2^2 \times 5! (\frac{1}{2!2!} +\frac{1}{4!})$$. However, this is wrong. Can someone explain to me why this is wrong?

Comment: What's the meaning of 2 different numbers(in the context of the question)?

Comment: What if the two numbers in front are the same?

Comment: You should first choose the two numbers, then use them to fill your places.

Comment: I do not understand what it is you are wanting to count.  Could you manually list them (*or at least a portion of them*)?  You are trying to count the list `11112, 11121, 11211, ..., 11122, 11212, 11221, ..., 22221, ..., 44445, ..., 55554`?  Those sequences of five digits with two distinct digits occurring where each digit is taken from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Comment: If so, do not make the mistake of assuming that the first two digits must be different.  If you assume both the first two must be different you will count `12111, 12112, 12121,...` but will miss out on `11112, 11221, ...`.  Further, do not make the mistake of overcounting by saying for instance "the first of my chosen digits will be a $1$ and occupy the first four positions and my second chosen number will be a $2$ and occupy the last position" vs "the first of my chosen digits will e a $2$ and occupy the last position and my second chosen number will be a $1$ occupying first four positions"

Comment: As for a correct approach to counting this... as WhatsUp correctly suggests, pick which two digits are used.  Then, pick which positions (*noting it cannot be all and it cannot be none*) are used by the smaller of those two digits.  The remaining positions go to the remaining number.  $\binom{5}{2}(2^5-2)$

Comment: @JMoravitz hi thanks for the comment. Yes, I want to figure out how many 5 digit numbers I can make that have two different digits. In my calculation, I just put the first and second numbers as different, but I have later multiplied it by 5! to take into account all combinations (and afterwards divided for the ones who repeat). Could you help me in finding where I am double counting?

Comment: Also, I have cleared up my working, so it hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning why you think you can multiply by $5!$ and then multiply by $(\frac{1}{2!\color{red}{2!}}+\frac{1}{4!})$ to fix whatever... or, at least, why you chose to do it in that order... Also, surely that should have been a $2!3!$, not a $2!2!$... If you insist on the $5!$ term and whatnot... then sure, the answer could be written $\left(\frac{5!}{2!3!}+\frac{5!}{1!4!}\right)\cdot 5\cdot 4$., choosing how to split the positions into a group of 2 and 3, or into a group of 1 and 4., choosing the digit used for the smaller group, and choosing the digit for the larger

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely right! This is what I meant to write. However, for some reason, I have a $2^3$ because I thought that I have 3 places where I have to chose one of the two digits. Do you know why this is wrong? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there were only three spaces to be filled.
If you were to choose numbers `1` and `2`, then to get
arrangements with *exactly* 2 different numbers you have
six possibilities.

```
112 121 211 122 212 221
```

The number of arrangements might be written as $2^3 - 2 = 8-2 = 6,$ because `111` and `222`, having only one of the numbers,
are not allowed.

Then you have to decide which two numbers to choose; there are
${5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways in which to choose them:

```
12 13 14 15 23 24 25 34 35 45
```

So the answer for three slots is $(2^3 - 2){5 \choose 2} = 60.$

Generalize.

Answer (score 1):

In your approach, before you tried to count the ways of ordering the numbers you already had all the orders that have different numbers in the first two positions.  You forced the first two to differ by saying there were $4$ choices for the second position.  You could follow up by counting the ones that agree in the first two numbers by saying you have $5$ choices for the first, $1$ for the second, $4$ for the third, and $2$ for each of the others.  That would get all the ones where the first two match and the third is different.  Now count the ones where the first three are the same and the fourth different and finally where the first four are the same.

The other approach is to first count the unordered possibilities.  There are $20$ combinations with three of one number and two of another.  Each of these can be ordered in $\frac {5!}{3!2!}$ ways, or in $5 \choose 2$ ways if you think of choosing the slots for the pair.  Similarly there are $20$ combinations with four of one number and one of another.  Count the ways of ordering them and add it all up.