# Combinations: Why is this wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want to find the number of different 5 digit numbers where 3 of the digits are different. Each digit can be from the set (1,2,3,4,5). Suppose I have the three digits $a,b,c$. We have to cases

$$a,b,c,a,a \text{  or   } a,b,c,a,b$$

In the first case we have $\frac{5!}{3!}$ different combinations and in the second we have $\frac{5!}{2!2!}$. Since $a,b,c$ are different integers from the set $(1,2,3,4,5)$, one will be able to take $5$ values, one will be able to take $4$ values, and one will be able to take $3$ values. Hence, the total number of combinations is $(\frac{5!}{3!}+ \frac{5!}{2!2!})\times5\times4\times3=3000$.

However, the answer to the question is given to be $1500$. Does anybody know where I have gone wrong?

It is worth noting that I have asked something very similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849051/number-of-possible-combinations/3849115#3849115), however, the comment section has gotten to large and also the answers seem to be suggestign I use a different method, but I want to know what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both of your cases you have a double-counting: in the first, swapping the positions of $b$ and $c$ in the string and swapping their values in the assignment will yield the same string of digits again (e.g., `12131` can be gotten either as $abaca$ with $a=1, b=2, c=3$ or as $acaba$ with $a=1, b=3, c=2$). There is a similar double-counting in the second with respect to swapping $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I wnated to ask you, if I had for example $a,b,c,d,a,a$ would I then have triple counting or 3! counting? Also, I wanted to ask you how do you intiutively think about this methodology and how do you notice that there will be double counting? (As I have an issue understanding why the double-counting should occur in this methodology)

Comment: @MathsWizzard Sorry for the late reply to your comment! In that case you'd have 3! counting — any permutation of $b,c,d$ with a corresponding permutation of the values assigned to them. And note that you got a little 'lucky' in your example; both quantities were double-counted (in different ways), so dividing the total sum by 2 worked here, but in general there's no guarantee of that. (For instance, the same question but with four digit numbers with two digits different.)

Comment: As for intuitive thinking about it, there are no guarantees — it's very easy to miss multiple counting. The best way I know of is to try and work through specific instances, and confirm for yourself whether there's a unique path to each member of the 'output set' or not. If you want another exercise, there's a classic bug that shows up sometimes in shufflers; one of these two procedures will give you a properly random distribution over all permutations, whereas the other will give you multiples of some permutations. See if you can figure out which:

Comment: The first version is to step through the array from i=1 to n and swap a[i] with an a[j] where j is chosen randomly from 1..n (i.e., with a random element from the array). The second version steps through the array from i=1 to n, but instead swaps a[i] with an a[j] where j is chosen randomly from i..n (i.e., a random element equal to or after i in the array).

Answer (score 0):

You have two cases:  3-1-1 or 2-2-1.

Case 3-1-1:

1. pick the three slots in which to place the repeated digit: $5\choose 3$.
2. choose the duplicated digits: 10
3. choose the two others together $9 \choose 2$

This gives 7200 possibilities.

Deal similarly with case 2-2-1.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! As as I said in the question, I know that I can do the whole problem can be done in a different way. However, I do not understand what is wrong with my current methodology. Could you assist me in understanding where I have gone wrong? I assume that it is in the first part, however, I do not understand why.